# JavaFX TreeView expand/collapse disclosure arrow bug

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

My Question: is there a workaround/fix for the bug I detail below or is it an issue in my code?

As you can see in the gif below, clicking on one disclosure (expand/collapse) node randomly affects the style of another disclosure arrow also sometimes an arrow will not rotate back on collapse, there seems to be no pattern, it could seemingly affect any other.

It looks like this problem was identified in an [OpenJDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095580) bug report.

But I'm using JDK 10 (18.03.20) 64bit for Windows, was this never fixed in standard JDK?

From my testing it seems that the `TreeItem`s have the correct values for `isExpanded()` even if they are displaying (styling) incorrectly.

I'm using the default style sheet (Modena), which defines the disclosure node rotation arrow as follows:

```
.tree-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow,
.tree-table-row-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-rotate: 90;
}
```

---

### [image: spooky action]

My classes are a pretty standard implementation as far as I can tell, if you need more just ask me.

---

```
XSContent rootContent = //...
TreeView<XSContent> tree = new TreeView<>(rootContent);
```

---

```
public final class XSTreeItem extends TreeItem<XSContent> {

    private boolean isLeaf;
    private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
    private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;

    public XSTreeItem(XSContent element) {
        super(element);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<TreeItem<XSContent>> getChildren() {
        if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
            isFirstTimeChildren = false;
            getChildren().setAll(getValue().buildChildren());
        }
        return super.getChildren();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
            isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
            isLeaf = getValue().isLeaf();
        }
        return isLeaf;
    }
}
```

---

```
public final class XSTreeCell extends TreeCell<XSContent> {

    public XSTreeCell() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(XSContent item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null || empty) {
            setStyle("");
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            item.configureCell(this);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class XSContent {

    public abstract boolean isLeaf(); // works as expected

    /** gets the children of this XSContent, works as expected */
    public abstract ObservableList<XSTreeItem> buildChildren();

    /** currently just setting the text of the cell */
    public abstract void configureCell(XSTreeCell cell);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding to my stylesheet an explicit rotation back to 0 for the arrow:

```
.tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow,
.tree-table-row-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-rotate: 0;
}
```

Adding the below is also required for it to work, even though this is already defined in the default Modena stylesheet:

```
.tree-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow,
.tree-table-row-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-rotate: 90;
}
```

*These style selectors are from the default Modena stylesheet of Java 2018-03-20*